# Defining closest observation in a data table

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

I have a `data.table` like the following:

```
    ID Date        Flag_1    Flag_2
    1  2016-01-01  1         0
    1  2016-02-01  0         0
    1  2016-03-01  0         1
    1  2016-04-01  0         0
    1  2016-05-01  1         0
    1  2016-06-01  0         0
    1  2016-07-01  0         1
    2  2017-03-01  0         0
    2  2017-04-01  1         0
    2  2017-05-01  0         0
    2  2017-06-01  0         0
    2  2017-07-01  0         1
```

I would like to create a `Flag_1_date` variable, which links the date of the preceding flag_1 event to the flag_2 event.

It is important to me, that only those flag_1 dates should be linked to the flag_2 event, which has the same ID as the flag_2 event.

```
    ID Date        Flag_1    Flag_2  Flag_1_date
    1  2016-01-01  1         0       0
    1  2016-02-01  0         0       0
    1  2016-03-01  0         1       2016-01-01
    1  2016-04-01  0         0       0
    1  2016-05-01  1         0       0
    1  2016-06-01  0         0       0
    1  2016-07-01  0         1       2016-05-01
    2  2017-03-01  0         0       0
    2  2017-04-01  1         0       0
    2  2017-05-01  0         0       0
    2  2017-06-01  0         0       2017-04-01
    2  2017-07-01  0         1       0
```

Comment: The first two dates are at the rows where Flag_2 is 1.  Why it is different for the last row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `na.locf()` from the `zoo` package to forward fill `Date` when `Flag_1==1` by `"ID"`, and subsequently omit the values where `Flag_2==0`:

```
library(zoo)
library(data.table)

dt[Flag_1==1, Flag_1_date := Date][
  ,Flag_1_date := na.locf(Flag_1_date), "ID"][
   Flag_2==0, Flag_1_date := NA
  ]
> dt
#   ID       Date Flag_1 Flag_2 Flag_1_date
# 1:  1 2016-01-01      1      0        <NA>
# 2:  1 2016-02-01      0      0        <NA>
# 3:  1 2016-03-01      0      1  2016-01-01
# 4:  1 2016-04-01      0      0        <NA>
# 5:  1 2016-05-01      1      0        <NA>
# 6:  1 2016-06-01      0      0        <NA>
# 7:  1 2016-07-01      0      1  2016-05-01
# 8:  2 2017-03-01      0      0        <NA>
# 9:  2 2017-04-01      1      0        <NA>
#10:  2 2017-05-01      0      0        <NA>
#11:  2 2017-06-01      0      0        <NA>
#12:  2 2017-07-01      0      1  2017-04-01
```

Comment: great solution!! Though I think it's missing the grouping condition as per OP's requirement of "same ID as the flag_2 event".

Comment: Worked perfectly, including the grouping by ID, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I guess the idiomatic way is

```
DT[Flag_2 == 1, v := 
  DT[Flag_1 == 1][.SD, on=.(ID, Date), roll = TRUE, x.Date]
]

    ID       Date Flag_1 Flag_2          v
 1:  1 2016-01-01      1      0       <NA>
 2:  1 2016-02-01      0      0       <NA>
 3:  1 2016-03-01      0      1 2016-01-01
 4:  1 2016-04-01      0      0       <NA>
 5:  1 2016-05-01      1      0       <NA>
 6:  1 2016-06-01      0      0       <NA>
 7:  1 2016-07-01      0      1 2016-05-01
 8:  2 2017-03-01      0      0       <NA>
 9:  2 2017-04-01      1      0       <NA>
10:  2 2017-05-01      0      0       <NA>
11:  2 2017-06-01      0      0       <NA>
12:  2 2017-07-01      0      1 2017-04-01
```

*How it works*

- `x[i, v := expr]` writes to the `v` column on rows selected by `i`.
- `.SD` is a stand-in for the current **S**ubset of **D**ata, so the `expr` is equivalent to

  ```
  DT[Flag_1 == 1][DT[Flag_2 == 1], on=.(ID, Date), roll = TRUE, x.Date]
  ```
- This line is another case of `x[i, j]`: `i = DT[Flag_2 == 1]` is used to select rows in `x = DT[Flag_1 == 1]`. The `on=` and `roll=` arguments pin down how this selection happens. For details, see `?data.table`. The `x.*` prefix in `j` indicates we want the column from `x`, not `i`.